# graphic image "src/value" from database

Tags: database, jsf, primefaces

i use primefaces on jsf framework, i have in my database a field that save the url source of where the image was saved for example:

Table Person:

```
id: integer
name: varchar
img: varchar ("C:\images\person\person1.jpg")
```

so, in my method in java y return that url string but when i put to the graphic image label 
it load like this `http://localhost:8080/..../C:\images\person\person1.jpg`

any ideas???

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{person.img}"/>
```

this line is in pure html

```
<img  src="C:\images\person\person1.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `file://C:\...` ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're expecting that image to be served by the default servlet or as a JSF resource since it's on your filesystem. This won't happen unless that imagine is part of your web-app.

In order to serve it, return a `StreamedContent` object from your method, something like this `return new StreamedContent(new FileInputStream(getPathFromDatabase()));`. Note that the returned property should be available in session scope or request scope, because the image is served by the Primefaces resource handler in a separate request. This means that if you return the StreamedContent object from a view scoped bean, it won't be available on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute of graphicImage is a relative url (or a binary stream if you implement StreamedContent), relative to your context.
That means it is appended to the url of your application, resulting in something like: `http://hostname:port/appname/relative_image_url`.